# Gulp is watching over an unspecified directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm having some problems understanding why Gulp watches a directory which is not specified by me.

Here's my Gulp task:

```
var _ = require('underscore'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    npath = require('path');

var BUILD_PATH = 'dist';

var base = [
    'manifest.json',
    'index.html'
];

var announce = function (event) {

    console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
};

gulp.task('copy:base', function () {

    return gulp.src(base)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(BUILD_PATH));
});

gulp.task('default', ['copy:base']);

gulp.watch(base, ['copy:base']).on('change', announce);
```

And here is my output:

```
[20:10:35] Finished 'copy:base' after 19 ms
[20:10:35] Starting 'default'...
[20:10:35] Finished 'default' after 33 μs
File /Users/abau/Documents/Projects/projecta/dist/ was added, running tasks... // why?
[20:10:35] Starting 'copy:base'...
[20:10:35] Finished 'copy:base' after 4.45 ms
```

Why does it watch for **dist/** directory? I haven't specified it anywhere. Also I've noticed that the directory **dist/** exists, it won't be watched anymore.

Thank you!

Comment: does changing var BUILD_PATH ='dist'; to something else affect the announce function?

Comment: I've managed to find out that it might be a concurency problem. For example, setting this:
setTimeout(function(){ gulp.watch(..); }, 1000); 
won't trigger the change.